# eager initialization singleton vs lazy initialization singleton

Tags: java, design-patterns, singleton

while pondering over singleton design pattern, I stuck between eager initialization singleton and  static block initialization singleton pattern.
Let's say  eager initialization singleton class code is -

```
public class EagerInitSingleton {

    private static final EagerInitSingleton instance = new EagerInitSingleton();

    //private constructor
    private EagerInitSingleton(){}

    public static EagerInitSingleton getInstance(){
        return instance;
    }
}
```

and static block singleton class code as followed-

```
public class StaticBlockSingleton {

    private static StaticBlockSingleton instance;

    private StaticBlockSingleton(){}

    //static block initialization for exception handling
    static{
        try{
            instance = new StaticBlockSingleton();
        }catch(Exception e){
            throw new RuntimeException("Exception occured in singleton instance");
        }
    }

    public static StaticBlockSingleton getInstance(){
        return instance;
    }
}
```

LETS NOT TALK ABOUT LAZY INITIALIZATION AND THREAD SAFETY HERE.
I want to figure out how two static blocks in Static block singleton making  a difference here.

Comment: why are you shouting at us?

Comment: I am here to learn something, so please ignore if you do not like it..:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference.

```
private static final EagerInitSingleton instance = new EagerInitSingleton();
```

is equivalent to

```
private static final EagerInitSingleton instance;

static {
    instance = new EagerInitSingleton();
}
```

Comment: so only exception handling is advantage?

Comment: I would say that if a static final field can be initialised in one line without a static block, do it. Only if it can't be done in one line (say it takes several lines of code to initialise, or if you need try/catch as in your example) then you should use a static block.

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help